# How to ignore a VI but still pass an error out?

Tags: labview

As part of debugging I want to skip a vi, but wiring/unwiring it every time is too tedious.

Is there a good strategy to ignore or "comment out" a vi?

Answer (score 2):

Add a [Diagram Disable Structure](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z000000P9NASA0&l=en-GB) around the VI, and wire the Error through in the Enabled case.  Then you can easily switch between calling the VI or not by changing which case is enabled.

Comment: Added link to the NI doc page. Note in LV 2009 onwards there is also the [Conditional Disable Structure](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/glang/conditional_disable_structure/) which can enable or disable code depending on the execution environment and so on.